# Access webcam and microphone input in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, webcam, microphone

How can you access the webcam and microphone in VB.net, assuming the user even has one?

I fail to see a My.Computer.Webcam or My.Computer.Microphone, both of which would probably have been a nice addition.

Thanks for the help! If there is no easy method for doing this, what is the name of the driver that handles this and what methods should I use to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cyclone, you can use [DirectShow .Net Library](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) to access the webcam and microphone here a example

- [Webcam using DirectShow.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/WebcamUsingDirectShowNET.aspx) (Vb .Net)

bye.

Comment: Ill try it, and let you know how it goes.