# Web cam interfaces in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, webcam

I have never worked with web cams in VB.net before.

Would anyone be able to recommend a free, stable, library that I can use in order to capture images from a web cam in a VB.net application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few questions on this subject already, and the consensus seems to be DirectShow is the way to go.  Try these links:

[Webcam usage in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/233455/12744)

[Access webcam and microphone input in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1451627/12744)

[Access web cam using vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7862400/12744)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! We have been using win32 api calls but it has proved to be unstable.